# find and update a document in elasticsearch2 using php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to find a document using ElasticSearch and update a field in it. The code is:

```
 require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();
                        $params = [
    'index' => 'myIndex',
    'type' => 'myCollection',
    'body' => [
        'query'=> [
                'match'=> [
                                'accessToken' => $accessToken
                ]
        ] ,
        'script' => 'ctx._source.deviceId= deviceId',
        'params' => [
            'deviceId' => $deviceId
        ],
        'upsert' => [
            'counter' => 1
        ]
    ]
];
```

The code is giving `500 Internal Error`. Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: not sure why has this been downvoted?

Comment: What do you see in the ES server logs?

Comment: Are you trying to update deviceId field with new value or you want to increase the value of deviceId (deviceid + 1,example:4+1) with adding 1 to it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the value of deviceid by 1 (mean if value of deviceid is 4 then u can increase it to 5 by adding 1 to it ),then follow below code

```
 'script' => 'ctx._source.deviceId= deviceId', 
    replace with 
     'script' => 'ctx._source.counter += deviceId',
```

Example:

```
$params = [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'type' => 'my_type',
        'id' => 'my_id',
        'body' => [
            'script' => 'ctx._source.counter += count',
            'params' => [
                'count' => 4
            ],
            'upsert' => [
                'counter' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $response = $client->update($params);
```

[Check i Elasticsearch php](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/_updating_documents.html)